# PCI error when installing 18.04.3

Tags: system-installation, pcie

[image: OCIe error] when trying to install ubuntu 18.04.3

Primary storage is SSD connected M2 interface I think.

EDIT:
Installation fails and the the crash reporter hangs too. When I cancel the report dialog, i am directed to read only command line logs

Comment: And what is the question?  Does the installation continue?

Comment: Edit your question and copy/paste the "command line logs", select the pasted text, click the {} icon to format that text, or paste them at paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: I cannot copy paste the text. it is not allowing me to.

Comment: You must enter edit mode, by clicking the small "edit" that appears directly under your question, or click [here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1207573/edit). Once pasted, select that text, and click the {} icon to format the text. If the text is large you could also paste the text at paste.ubuntu.com. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: no. not this site. the terminal is not allowing me to copy the logs

Comment: Are you able to copy a single word or single sentence? Do you get any error messages when you try to copy the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting AER (advanced error reporting) PCIe bus errors. Although they're correctable, you should find out what device is generating them.

In `terminal`...

`sudo lspci -tv`

Locate the device associated with device 1b.2, and try to identify a cure. It might be a driver/firmware issue. ie: a comm device

The installation **may** be able to continue, but you may still have to recheck for problems after rebooting to the newly installed system.

---

If it's just log file noise, you can eliminate it with...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer